# how to code to echo user post value before submission in print pdf?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have an html page which contains radio checks and select menu and input file.

I need to print the values the user choose in pdf before insert submission, 
but when I use `echo $var` it is empty and doesn't print anything,  or prints the last choice which was already submitted not the new value which the user just chose

for example :

if user chooses

(Sunday) from menu   and
(Satisfactory) from check

I want when user click Save will print Sunday and Satisfactory

PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
   $uday=$_POST['insday'];
   $aval1=$_POST['case1'];
   $file1=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["f1"]["tmp_name"]));
$query="INSERT INTO `apron`(`uday`, `cleannessFODs`, `cleannessFOD2`)  VALUES ('$uday','$aval1','$file1')";
   $result_query=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

HTML code

```
<div class="select1 select-div">Day :
    <select id="insday" name="insday" class="auto-style5" style="width: 26%">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option></select></div><br>

<input type="radio" id="demo-priority-satisfied" value='Satisfactory' name="case1" ><label for="demo-priority-satisfied">Satisfactory</label>
<input type="radio" id="demo-priority-normal" value='Unsatisfactory' name="case1"><label for="demo-priority-normal">Unsatisfactory</label>
<input type="radio" id="demo-priorit-satisfied" value='Not applicable' name="case1" ><label for="demo-priorit-satisfied">Not applicable</label>
<input type="radio" id="demo-priort-satisfied" value='Not inspected' name="case1" ><label for="demo-priort-satisfied">Not inspected</label>
<input type="file" name="f1"  id="file-input" multiple/>

<div id = "tabr" style="width: 76%">
<p><h2>APRON DAILY INSPECTION CHECKLIST :</h2></p>

<p>Inspector Day :<?php echo$uday?></p>
<p>check : <?php echo$aval1?></p>
</div>
<input type='submit' name="save" id="save" onclick="createrPDF()" value='Save' />
```

script to create pdf

```
<script>
    function createrPDF() {
        var sTable = document.getElementById('tabr').innerHTML;

        var style = "<style>";
        style = style + "table {width: 100%;font: 17px Calibri;}";
        style = style + "table, th, td {border: solid 1px #DDD; border-collapse: collapse;";
        style = style + "padding: 2px 3px;text-align: center;}";
        style = style + "</style>";

        // CREATE A WINDOW OBJECT.
        var win = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=700');

        win.document.write('<html><head>');

        win.document.write('<title>Apron INSPECTION</title>');   // <title> FOR PDF HEADER.
        win.document.write(style);          // ADD STYLE INSIDE THE HEAD TAG.
        win.document.write('</head>');
        win.document.write('<body>');
        win.document.write(sTable);         // THE TABLE CONTENTS INSIDE THE BODY TAG.
        win.document.write('</body></html>');

        win.document.close();   // CLOSE THE CURRENT WINDOW.

        win.print();    // PRINT THE CONTENTS.

    }
</script>
```

Attachment input file it is display successfully in print pdf 
but select and check not

Comment: I assume you mean `<p>Inspector Day :<?php echo $uday; ?></p>
<p>check : <?php echo $aval1; ?></p>` and that you do not expect those to print when just clicking the button. Three is a difference between server code and client code and PHP renders the php vars when the page loads and needs to go to the server to change anything

Comment: Also if this is in a form, you need to preventDefault the submit button click

Comment: so what do think ..there is any way to display values before submitted to db

Comment: if i preventdefult also not display any value

Comment: if there is way to display it after insert in db I ok with it but i don;t know any way to do that

Comment: Search AJAX PHP